# Boost and ssl client server building issue on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, boost

I have installed boost as a third library when I install pcl (Point Cloud Library).

Now I am trying to run client and server programs http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp

When trying to link the required libraries:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/boost/  server.cpp -o server -lboost_system -lssl -lpthread
```

following error appears:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccRbD849.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   'ERR_reason_error_string@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO
>   missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

When I searched the ***usr*** folder the Boost folder exists only inside ***include*** subfolder.

What can I do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> [...] libcrypto.so: [...] DSO missing from command line

spells it out! You are missing

```
-lcrypto
```

on the linker command line. In fact I always use `-lssl -lcrypto` in tandem

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought the problem with a missing folder.