# Errors compiling boost example of ssl client

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile the boost example from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp . For some reason I'm getting the following errors and I don't know how to fix them:

```
ssl_client.cpp:37:25: error: ‘boost::asio::ssl::verify_context’ has not been declared
ssl_client.cpp: In constructor ‘client::client(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ssl::context&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::iterator)’:
ssl_client.cpp:27:13: error: ‘class boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >’ has no member named ‘set_verify_mode’
ssl_client.cpp:27:29: error: ‘verify_peer’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio::ssl’
ssl_client.cpp:28:13: error: ‘class boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >’ has no member named ‘set_verify_callback’
ssl_client.cpp:31:5: error: ‘async_connect’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio’
ssl_client.cpp: In member function ‘bool client::verify_certificate(bool, int&)’:
ssl_client.cpp:48:54: error: request for member ‘native_handle’ in ‘ctx’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
ssl_client.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ssl_client.cpp:143:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>::basic_context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)’
ssl_client.cpp:143:68: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:47:3: note: boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<Service>::basic_context(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) [with Service = boost::asio::ssl::context_service]
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:47:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:35:7: note: boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>::basic_context(const boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>&)
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:35:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method’ to ‘const boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>&’
```

I'm currently compiling with the following line:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/boost -Wall -o main ssl_client.cpp -lboost_system
```

And I recently installed boost through:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I'm sure there's an easy fix, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

========================================================================
Update:

I've now tried compiling with:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/boost -Wall -o main ssl_client.cpp -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl -lpthread
```

but I'm still getting the following errors:

```
ssl_client.cpp:37:25: error: ‘boost::asio::ssl::verify_context’ has not been declared
ssl_client.cpp: In constructor ‘client::client(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ssl::context&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::iterator)’:
ssl_client.cpp:27:13: error: ‘class boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >’ has no member named ‘set_verify_mode’
ssl_client.cpp:27:29: error: ‘verify_peer’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio::ssl’
ssl_client.cpp:28:13: error: ‘class boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >’ has no member named ‘set_verify_callback’
ssl_client.cpp:31:5: error: ‘async_connect’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio’
ssl_client.cpp: In member function ‘bool client::verify_certificate(bool, int&)’:
ssl_client.cpp:48:54: error: request for member ‘native_handle’ in ‘ctx’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
ssl_client.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ssl_client.cpp:143:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>::basic_context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)’
ssl_client.cpp:143:68: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:47:3: note: boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<Service>::basic_context(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) [with Service = boost::asio::ssl::context_service]
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:47:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:35:7: note: boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>::basic_context(const boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>&)
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/basic_context.hpp:35:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method’ to ‘const     boost::asio::ssl::basic_context<boost::asio::ssl::context_service>&’
```

Comment: seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29118744/85371

Comment: Just tried it actually, with the -lcrypto, -lssl and -lpthread, but I'm still getting a ton of errors for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! It was because apt-get was giving me boost version 1.46 and I needed version 1.48. I did the following to fix it:

```
apt-get purge libboost-all-dev
```

and

```
apt-get install libboost1.48-all-dev
```

Thanks to: http://spencernusbaum.me/blog.php#106